# Audio tag inside the bootstrap modal working fine but the download button position is out of modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html5-audio

I'm trying to add audio tag inside the modal but the download button is out of modal, this is tested on chrome.

[image]

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Open modal with Audio
</button>

<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <audio controls controlsList="download" style="width:100%">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know we can hide the download button but in case we want to keep it, not sure if there is a solution. here is the code on [pen](https://codepen.io/fayekramzy/pen/xxxNaQd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply transform: none; property on the modal-dialog class.

Comment: you mean transform property, not transition. But yes, I set the transform to none and it works fine! Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this seems like a common issue using `<audio>` tag and occasionally `<video>` or `<iframe>`. There are certain ways to modify the style minimally but cannot solve the problem.

What I can come up it's to create your own download link through a tag. disable the original download link and create your own download link and "fit" into `<audio>` tag style. The new link will open the entire `<audio>` tag into a new page then use the download link if necessary.

You can try out the code below in your codepen. It seems like Stackoverflow blocks popup in sandbox.

Nevertheless, I believe this is quite complex but you can take it as an idea.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Open modal with Audio
</button>

<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body d-flex">
        <div class="w-100 d-flex" style="background-color: #f1f3f4; border-radius: 2rem">
        <audio controls controlsList="nodownload" style="width:100%; position:fix">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
         <a class="text-center" target="_blank" style="line-height:54px; margin-right:1rem" href="https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/horse.ogg">Icon
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/horse.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```